# 'Client' object has no attribute 'text' Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have models in my project

```
class Client(models.Model):
    """Аккаунт, с которого рассылаются сообщения"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 70)
    avatar = models.ImageField('Аватар', upload_to = 'sender/', blank = True)
    phoneNumberRegex = RegexValidator(regex = r"^\+?\d{8,15}$")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators = [phoneNumberRegex], max_length = 16, unique = True)
    api_id = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    api_hash = models.CharField(max_length=33)
    proxy = models.ForeignKey(
        Proxy,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='owner',
        verbose_name='Владелец',
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Аккаунт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Аккаунты'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Sender(models.Model):
    """Рассылка"""
    NUMBER_PHONE = 'По номеру телефона'
    USER_NAME = 'По имени пользователя'
    SENDER_CHOICES = (
        (NUMBER_PHONE, 'По номеру телефона'),
        (USER_NAME, 'По имени пользователя'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        'Название рассылки',
        max_length=10,
    )
    text = models.TextField(
        'Сообщение',
        max_length=4096,
    )
    type = models.CharField(
        'Тип рассылки',
        max_length=30,
        choices=SENDER_CHOICES,
        default=NUMBER_PHONE,
        db_index=True,
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='Mailer',
        verbose_name='Автор',
    )
    sender_man = models.ForeignKey(
        Client,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='Sender_man',
        verbose_name='Отправитель',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

From these models I create forms

```
class SenderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sender
        fields = ('name', 'text', 'type', 'author', 'sender_man')


class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('name', 'last_name', 'description', 'avatar', 'phone_number', 'api_id', 'api_hash', 'proxy')
```

When I create an instance of the `Client` model, everything goes without problems. The page is rendered, I fill out the form, submit it, and a new instance of the model appears in the database.

The problem occurs when I try to enter a page where there should be a form with which an instance of the `Sender` model will be added

http://127.0.0.1:8000/sender/creating/

I get an error 'Client' object has no attribute 'text'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rBwk.png)

Why is he talking about the 'Client' model? In this form, I am accessing the `Sender` model!

Help me please. I can't deal with this at all.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'sender'

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.index, name='index'),
  
    path('proxy/', views.proxy_list, name='proxy'),

    path('proxy/add/', views.proxy_add, name='new_proxy'),

    path('client/', views.client_list, name='client'),

    path('client/add/', views.client_add, name='new_client'),

    path('sender/', views.sender_list, name='sender'),

    path('sender/creating/', views.sender_create, name='new_sender'),

]
```

views.py

```
def sender_create(request):
    form = SenderForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        sender = form.save(commit=False)
        sender.author = request.user
        sender.save()
        return redirect('sender:sender')
    return render(request, 'sender/addsender.html', {'form': form})
```

template addsender.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}
Форма заявления
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-8">
      <br>
      <p class="h2">
        Создание рассылки
      </p>
    </div>
      <div class="col-4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-left">
    <div class="col-md-6 p-5">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'sender:new_sender' %}" class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group row my-3 p-3">
              <p>
                  {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
              </p>
              <p>
                  {{ form.text|as_crispy_field }}
              </p>
              <p>
                  {{ form.type|as_crispy_field }}
              </p>
              <p>
                  {{ form.sender_man|as_crispy_field }}
              </p>
              <br>
              <hr>
              <br>
              <br>
              <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-8 mx-auto">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="ЗАПУСТИТЬ РАССЫЛКУ">
              </div>
        </form>
      </body>
      </body>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried deleting the database, deleting migrations.
In the `def sender_create(request)` function, I tried to comment out individual lines, and came to the conclusion that the error occurs in this line `form = SenderForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)`

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](/tour) Try debugging with a good IDE before posting questions with many code files and lots of code. See [mcve] and [ask]. I use [the PyCharm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) for Python files. You can use it to debug easily and find the cause of the error.

Comment: In `Client` model's `__str__()`, you are asking for `self.text`, but the `Client` model doesn't have this property. Also it's called when you render sender, because the form is trying to render the foreign key `sender_man` from `Sender`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Here you have mentioned self.text but do not have text field in client. replace it with name

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```